# java testing servlet outside servlet container

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, servlets

I have the next problem. I want to test servlet (it works if I try manually via Tomcat):

```
package controller;

import blabla

@Controller
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriesDAO categoriesDAO;


    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Called init");//In my case it is not called
        super.init();
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = getAction(req);
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        if (action.startsWith("xxx")) {
            List<Category> categories = categories.getCategories();
            req.setAttribute("categories", categories);

            req.getRequestDispatcher("xxx.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }}}
```

My test:

```
 package servlet;

    import blabla

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"})
    public class MainServletTest extends TestCase{

        @Autowired
        private CategoriesDAO categories;

        @Mock
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
           categories.truncate();
           categories.setLoaded(false);
           Project.projectid = 0;
           Category.categoryid = 0;
        }

        @Mock
        private HttpServletResponse response;

        @Mock
        private HttpSession session;

        @Mock
        private RequestDispatcher rd;

        @Test
        public void testCategories() throws ServletException, IOException {
            // given
            categoriesDAO.add(new Category("name3"));
            categoriesDAO.add(new Category("name4"));
            when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("/test/xxx");
            when(request.getContextPath()).thenReturn("/test");
            when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
            //when

            MainServlet main = new MainServlet();
            main.init(getServletConfig());//This line doesnot work. My tries
            main.doGet(request, response);

            //then
            verify(request).setAttribute("categories", categories.getCategories());
        }
    }
```

Problem is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:48)
    at servlet.MainServletTest.testCategories(MainServletTest.java:67)
    blabla
```

I think the problem is that Tomcat calls init() method (and Spring initialise CategoriesDAO). In my case *init()* is not called and Autowired object is not initiated. My question is how to call *init()* outside Servlet Container?

Comment: Where is you CategoriesDAO  defined?

Comment: Why don't you mock the DAO? Why do you annotated a servlet with @Controller? Why don't you make it a real Spring controller instead of a servlet? You shouldn't need a spring context for a **unit** test. Just mock your collaborators.

Comment: For the test in application-context-test.xml via spring scaning. For the servlet in application-context.xml and spring is connected via web.xml to Web application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the xml file in which you have defined your DAO to @ContextConfiguration as well. Sth like

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml","classpath*:dao.xml"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found there is JUnit Extension called Cactus. It can be used to test servlets without containers:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_extensions.htm